# gdal.h file missing when trying to install gdal in windows 10 using pip (no Anaconda)

Tags: python, windows, installation, pip, gdal

**Windows 10**

**Python 3.12**

**Not using Anaconda**

**gdal version: 3.8.0**

```
pip install gdal
Collecting gdal
  Using cached GDAL-3.8.0.tar.gz (802 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: gdal
  Building wheel for gdal (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [141 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
```

the first error is

```
extensions/gdalconst_wrap.c(3013): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gdal.h': No such file or directory
```

Where should that file be in?

I have installed
**gdal-3.8.0-1930-x64-core.msi**
and
**osgeo4w**

The following system vars were set

**GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins**

**GDAL_DATA=C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal-data**

**PATH** has **C:\Program Files\GDAL\** in it

Comment: run `pip install` with option `-v` or `--verbose` and it should show you more details. `gdal.h` suggests that it use `C/C++` code and it may need `C/C++` compiler. It may need also `C/C++` header files for `gdal` - it means `source code` for `gdal`, not only `precompiled` `gdal`. Python need `gdal source code` to compile some code to work with `precompiled gdal`. On Linux it would need to install packed with postfix `-dev` (like `development`) but I don't know what name it may have on Windows